# can we create user's home directory with space in name? like /test 123

Tags: linux, user-management

i need to map some path like /data/test 123 as home directory for user testuser, but it is not accepting space in home directory path ?

it is not allowing me to change path using `usermod -m -d /new path username`.

Comment: why is a space a requirement? Can't you use underscore or something like that?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using the `-d` switch to useradd

```
useradd -d '/home/test 123' test123
```

Adding the single quotes `'` also works for usermod but note that this will break all sorts of stuff that isn't expecting a space e.g.

```
su - test123
-bash: [: /home/test: binary operator expected
```

Similarly if you use something that isn't test e.g. `tst 123`

```
su - test123
-bash: [: /home/tst: binary operator expected
```

Save yourself a lot of pain and don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you really need a home path with a space, create it as a link, i.e.

```
/data/test 123 > /data/test_123
```

That way, real work can be done with 'test_123', but you can make it look as 'test 123' when required?